# Ambiguous use of 'observe' - myQuery.observe(GFEventType)

Tags: jquery, ios, swift, observers, geofire

I'm trying to find users via GeoFire , for some reason this syntax isnt working for me....

```
  func findUsers () {
    guard let userLat = userDefault.value(forKey: "current_location_latitude") as? String, let userLong = userDefault.value(forKey: "current_location_longitude") as? String else {return}

    let location: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(Double(userLat)!), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(Double(userLong)!))

    myQuery = geoFire.query(at: location, withRadius: distance)

 --->  ** myQuery.observe(GFEventType.keyEntered) { (key, location) ** in
        print(key)
    }


}
```

giving me an error of "Ambiguous use of 'observer'"

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
func findUsers () {
    guard let userLat = userDefault.value(forKey: "current_location_latitude") as? String, let userLong = userDefault.value(forKey: "current_location_longitude") as? String else {return}

    let location: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(Double(userLat)!), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(Double(userLong)!))

    myQuery = geoFire.query(at: location, withRadius: distance)

    myQuery.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key, location) in
        print(key)
    })
}
```